# Date parsing using regular expression

Tags: java, regex, string, date

I am using regular expression to parse date formats from a string . It could be like

```
1/1/11
01/01/11
01/01/2011
01/1/2011
1/11/2011
1/11/11
11/1/11
```

Java code:

```
public static String getDateFromRemarks(String str) {
    String parsedDate = null;
    if (str != null) {
        String regex = ".*([0-3]?[0-9]/[0-3]?[0-9]/(?:[0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2}).*";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            parsedDate = matcher.group(1);
        }
    }
    return parsedDate;
}
```

Input:

```
kjs22/12/2011 kjdflk
```

Output:

```
2/12/2011
```

Input:

```
kjs2/12/2011 kjdflk
```

Output:

```
2/12/2011
```

I should get date as

```
22/12/2011
```

Comment: Why use regexes? Consider using Joda Time and its `DateTimeFormatter` instead (or the Java 8 datetime API if you have Java 8; or threetenbp)

Comment: Due to certain limitation , I cannot use all these

Comment: Well, anyway, your result is expected. Hint: `.*` swallows everything, then it backtracks.

Comment: You should have also listed the limitation as why you cant use standard APIs for date parsing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of your initial `.*`. It swallows everything then backtracks.

And since the first digit is optional before your first /, the regex is satisfied with only one digit even if there are two.

Change your initial `.*` to `[^\d]*`.

Comment: This won't work if prefix contains digits like `k000111js22/12/2011 kjdflk`

Comment: Yeah well, OP hasn't given any other examples, so I assume this is enough